# html select dropdown on mobile device

Tags: html, ios, css

I have problem with select html element.
when i change my chrome mode to the device mode like apple ipad or anything else select element getting corrupted. some black space surround the dropdown.
Here is the source code and the screenshot.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <select>
    <option>test one</option>
    <option>test two</option>
    <option>test three</option>
    <option>test gour</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

[image]

```
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<select>
<option>test one</option>
<option>test two</option>
<option>test three</option>
<option>test gour</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Also try it on [ScreenFly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) or another tools, check it's chrome issue or your `html`

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome right now. I opened other websites (ie. jsfiddle) with select tag, and I see the same behaviour. It looks like Chrome bug.

Comment: @KamilD Yes, it's seems that this is chrome bug.

Answer (score 0):

In your media query, set a width on the select element. This will cause the select box to be the correct width, but any text longer than the box will be cut off.

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* ... */
    select {
        width: 150px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This edit.

```html
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/stylesheet">
html, body, div, span,object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/**/
.select-wrapper {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 3em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-width: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    width: 100%;
    width: calc(100% + 2em);
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
/**/
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="select-wrapper">
     <select class="select">
       <option value="1" selected="selected">test one</option>
       <option value="2">test two</option>
       <option value="3">test three</option>
       <option value="4">test four</option>
     </select>
     <span class="select-icon entypo-arrow-combo"></span>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```